# Upgrade result in undefined method `visit_Array'

Tags: ruby, activerecord, yaml

I am trying to upgrade the Ruby version on my system from 1.8 to 1.9 or 2.0.

But I have written a program that I will like to upgrade too, but I am having a problem 
I can't figure out how to solve.

It did run fine under Ruby 1.8 using Active Record 2.3.18, but now I have installed
Ruby 2.0.0 and Active Record 4.0.11.

But it now complains about an undefined method 'visit_Array' in the Psych framework.

Here is a stack trace of my program:

```
>> ~/stocks $ ruby20 StockFind.rb IBM
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit': undefined method `visit_Array' for #<Psych::Visitors::ToRuby:0x88c0d90> (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:267:in `block in revive_hash'
from /home/shs/stocks/Stock.rb:26:in `each_slice'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:266:in `revive_hash'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:141:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:240:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:35:in `to_ruby'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:130:in `load'
from /home/shs/stocks/StockStore.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
from StockFind.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Also the `each_slice` function is defined like this:

```
class Array
  def each_slice(slice_length)
    last=slice_length-1
    i=0
    while (i+last)<self.length do
      yield(self[i..i+last],i,i+last)
      i+=1
    end
    i
  end
end
```

Comment: You should consider using spaces between your operators and in your code. They help readability; That'seasytotell. It's a maintenance thing and a really good habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rename the method `each_slice` in your code, since this method is part of the [`Enumerable`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice) APIs since 1.8.6. The `psych` gem uses it, and expects a different behavior.

Comment: Thank, that took care of that error, moving on to the next error. :-)